# Why is Postgres idle transaction not terminated?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, transactions

I have a long running idle query that is not automatically terminated.

I have set both the max timeouts to 2h (very long I know)

```
> select name,setting from pg_settings where name='statement_timeout' OR name='idle_in_transaction_session_timeout';

                name                 | setting
-------------------------------------+---------
 idle_in_transaction_session_timeout | 7200000
 statement_timeout                   | 7200000
```

However I have this `idle` query (not `idle_in_transaction`) that is leftover from an application that crashed

```
> SELECT pid, age(clock_timestamp(), query_start), state, usename, query
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE  query NOT ILIKE '%pg_stat_activity%'
ORDER BY query_start desc;

17117 | 02:11:40.795487 | idle  | ms1-user | select distinct ....
```

Postgres 11.13 running on AWS Aurora

Can anyone explain why/what's missing?

Comment: "*I have a long running idle query*" - makes no sense. Either it's idle, then it's not running a query. Or it's running a query - then it's not idle.

Comment: I mean...semantics...you get the idea

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` does not terminate idle sessions, but sessions that are "idle in transaction". For the latter, you can use `idle_session_timeout` introduced in PostgreSQL v14.

In your case, the problem are the TCP keepalive settings. With the default keepalive settings on Linux, it takes the server around 2 hours and 14.5 minutes to figure out that the other end of the connection is no longer there. So wait a few minutes more :^)

If you want to reduce the time, you can set the PostgreSQL parameters `tcp_keepalives_idle`, `tcp_keepalives_interval` and `tcp_keepalives_count` if Amazon allows you to do that. If they don't, complain.

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot upgrade to v14 as it is not supported yet for our setup :(. We are on 11 and could go to 13 but I think there is no gain in this situation for that.

As for the tcp settings, I have seen queries stuck in `idle` state for days, so I think it cannot be that?

Basically these queries come from a containerised java app, running on a host shared with other containers.

When the container is terminated, is there some underlying config on the (linux) host meaning that this query still has a connection? It really feels like the query is stuck in postgres and not the host.

Comment: If the `state` is `'idle'`, nothing is "stuck". The server is just waiting for the client to send the next statement, and the query shown is just the last one that was executed on this connection. I am no specialist on containers, but since processes in a container are just normal operating system processes, I don't see why things should be different there. If there is nobody on the other end, nobody can answer to the keepalive packet.